# Why is a transaction_safe function not recognized by std::is_function when compiling with GCC 7, libstdc++, and -fgnu-tm?

Tags: c++, type-traits, libstdc++, transactional-memory

Is the compilation failure below due to a libstdc++ defect, or is this behavior compliant with the Transactional Memory TS ([n4514](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4514.pdf))?

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_function_v<void() transaction_safe>, "");
int main() {}
```

Comment: Open up your `type_traits` header and look if partial specializations that include `transaction_safe` in the function signature have been added to `is_function`'s implementation. If not, they haven't gotten around to doing that.

Comment: They aren't there. I'm just wondering whether the omission was intentional.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, please file a GCC bug report.